# How to fix classpath in gradle generated startScripts

Tags: gradle

I am building a simple application which starts well using gradle wrapper.

Now I would like to start it using a shell script. I am trying to use gradle startScripts task provided by Application plugin to generate such a script.

Here are the commands I tried:

```
n@laptop - ./gradlew clean build
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed

n@laptop - ./build/scripts/simple
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.11
targetCompatibility = 1.11

application {
    mainClassName = 'Main'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2")
    compile("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.0.Final")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.1")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.8")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.0.16.Final")
    compile("javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.0")
    compile("org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0")
    compile("com.beust:jcommander:1.72")

    testCompile ("junit:junit:4.12")

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8"

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run the generated script from Gradle’s `build` directory directly. The script is only generated there but meant to be used as part of one of the built distribution archives under `build/distributions/`. For example (assuming that your project is called `simple` and we’re on a Unix system):

```sh
# create a directory where we will install the built ZIP distribution
mkdir installdir
# unzip the ZIP distribution to the new install directory
unzip build/distributions/simple.zip -d installdir
# run the application using the generated script from the distribution
installdir/simple/bin/simple
```

For reference, here’s what the install directory will look like for your build (with the generated start scripts in the `bin` directory):

```
installdir/simple/
├── bin
│   ├── simple
│   └── simple.bat
└── lib
    ├── classmate-1.3.4.jar
    ├── commons-io-1.3.2.jar
    ├── simple.jar
    ├── hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar
    ├── jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
    ├── jackson-core-2.9.8.jar
    ├── jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar
    ├── jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar
    ├── javax.el-3.0.0.jar
    ├── javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar
    ├── jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
    ├── jcommander-1.72.jar
    └── validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
```

---

Alternatively, you can run your program directly from Gradle using [the `run` task](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks) of the application plugin:

```sh
./gradlew run
```